# How to make maven install test packages in local repo without running them

Tags: java, maven, ant

this might seem like a straightforward question and there are a lot of answers but none of them actually work. People always suggest to use -Dmaven.test.skip=true or -DskipTests but these options completely skip the tests and they are never moved to the local repo, so when I install other modules which depend on the existence of the tests in local repo they fail.

I need the tests to go under the the same group id and artifact id as the main classes only with different classifier and scope so I could reference them in other project like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtificatId</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you generating the test-jar with configuration of maven-jar-plugin? `-Dmaven.test.skip` will not even compile the tests, while `-DskipTests` should just skip the execution not preventing any other phase (including install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This will package the `-test` classified jar. Be aware that if you use `-DskipTests`, surefire and failsafe will skip the executions of the tests, while if you use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` tests will completely be ignored by surefire, failsafe and compiler.

Comment: We use svn and I don't want to mess with pom file, I don't want revert it during each svn update. Is it possible to specify this option through settings.xml?

Comment: you could configure the plugin execution inside a profile, or you can launch the maven goal directly as `mvn jar:test-jar` and use @Zoltán answer below to install; however there is no point in not rebuilding the test jar when you rebuild the main artifact (if you don't have some good reason you didn't tell).